# Real devices not showing in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Hi i am trying to run my app through usb i have turned on debug mode also install via usb but after connecting device to android studio i am not able to show the device in android studio Any help?

[image]

Comment: Can you see it running `adb devices` ?
Maybe try to change your USB cable.
I had the same issue for a while recently. Somehow update AS solved the problem. I'm running Android Studio 3.2 Canary 18.

Comment: Device drive is showing in my computer but not in android studio i have checked by changing devices and usb also.

Comment: I have edit configurations i select in target deployment usb only but it's not working in my case.

Comment: Ok thank you for answer and comment i have found the solution instead of running the app from run button i tryed it with Debug app (Shift +9) button and it worked successfully.

Comment: when i try it second time my above solution not worked then reinstall android sdk from sdk manager and it's works Thank you to all of you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Check in 'Android device monitor', in Android Studio click on Tools menu -> Android -> Android device monitor